# AEM Developer Mode: Not all components are appearing in Side Panel

Tags: vue.js, adobe, aem

When switching from AEM Edit Mode to Developer Mode on my AEM 6.5 instance I don't see all Components available on my page. I would like to use the execution timing information + jump to crx/de. The page is based on AEM core components and uses Template Editor. There are no logfile errors or JS issues.
On the same instance Core Components Example is installed and I do see all components. 
What might be wrong with my custom template?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it has to do with custom JS. When I remove it Component Info is shown. Will investigate further.

Edit:
Developer Mode uses HTML Comments. Those have been removed from DOM via Vue. To prevent that add `comments: true` in AEM edit mode while mounting the APP. Further info: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#comments